# TCPClient - stops receiving data after some time

Tags: c#, tcp

I have wrote a code to listen data on particular port in TCP mode.
Now the problem here is that the below code receives some data from the remote and after sometime it does not receive anything

I have check the wireshark and data is coming over there
I have check the TCPView, port (2-3 entries of same port is there) is open with the application but few port status stays as "ESTABLISHED" and one port is saying "LISTENING"

If i am checking the wireshark for missign data detail, then i found that remote IP-Port pair is stated as "ESTABLISHED" in TCPView but it cannot write anything in log file

My question is why the no data received in my application. Is there anything wrong in the code? I have tried every option which google can provide but there is no luck.

```
       TcpListener tcpListenerDeviceResponse = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localIP), 6005));
        tcpListenerDeviceResponse.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            using (TcpClient client = tcpListenerDeviceResponse.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    Socket skSource = client.Client;
                    int i;
                    var data2 = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        string strResponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2, 0, i);
                        // Insert the data in log text file
                        // process data
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
       }
       tcpListenerDeviceResponse.Stop();
```

Comment: Don't trust the logging code to be reliable.  Use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

One Reason could be Timeout!

Assuming Transmitting socket doesn't send data for more than Receiving socket's timeout, it will result in Timeout Error and will break the `while` loop and Close the socket.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx) MSDN link might help you!

Also, I would suggest you to close the socket only if it is breaking `while` for other reasons except Timeout. If Timeout occurs, Go on reading again.